# LDAP authentication with Django

Tags: python, django, ldap

I met some problem when I authenticate Django with LDAP

I am using `django-auth-ldap` and codes are below:

```
view.py

username = ''
password = ''
state = ''

if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.REQUEST.get('username')
        password = request.REQUEST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            state = "Valid account"
            return redirect('/home/')
        else:
            state = "Inactive account"
    return render_to_response('login.html')

else:
    return redirect('/home/')
```

and the form in HTML is:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    User Name: <input type="text" name="username">         
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Log on</button>
</form>
```

and the setting.py is:

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "server"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "My_DN"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "My_Password"

FILTER_STR =  "(&(cn=*%s*)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" % "%(user)s"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("search_words",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, FILTER_STR)

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL:1,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS:0,
}

# Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

The authenticate value in view always return None, but I don't know why.

Is there anyone who can solve my problem? Or help me to check my codes.

Thank you.

Comment: For reference, the link to the docs is  https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Answer (score 0):

use auth decorator login_required like:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
      'template_name': 'APPNAME/login.html'
    }),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', {
      # using logout_then_login, no logout template is needed
      #'template_name': 'APPNAME/logout.html'
    }),
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def index(request):
    msg = "welcome to the index view"
    context = {'request': request, 'msg': msg}
    return render(request, 'APPNAME/index.html', context)
```